# Custom sound with NSTimer

Tags: ios, swift, audio

I have a timer that counts down based on input. I want it to play a boxing (round end) sound when it hits 0.

I searched around and found this

```
    // Load
    let soundURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(mysoundname, withExtension: "wav")
    var mySound: SystemSoundID = 0
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundURL, &mySound)

    // Play
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(mySound);
```

I have the following questions:

1. where do you put the load section? Anywhere specific or it doesn't matter?
2. are these sounds already preloaded/stored somewhere? How does one get a custom sound?

Thanks in advance,
Ace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code:

```
    // Load Sound
    soundlocation = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("BoxingBellStart", withExtension: "wav")!

    player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: soundlocation, error: &Error)
    player.volume = 1

    // Play Sound
    player.play()
```

BoxingBellStart is a .wav file located in my project